# Turning SSLEngine on causes ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl

I am trying to configure my SSL certificate on a new installation of Ubuntu 15.10. I have installed the certificate files and the private key in the required directory:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/pts.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/msk.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/intermediate.crt
```

When I do `sudo service apache2 restart` I am then prompted to `Enter passphrase for SSL/TLS keys for www.mydomain.com:443 (RSA): ********` and since this process reports back with no errors, I am assuming that I have at least installed the certificates and private key correctly, otherwise I would have expected an error at this stage.

My problem is that I receive ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to load the site. The problem arises when I enable SSLEngine on in my VirtualHost directive.

I have verified that mod_ssl is enabled and OpenSSL is also installed. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Is apache2 listening on the relevant IP:Port (443) and is the port open in all the firewalls between you and the server.

Comment: I have `<IfModule ssl_module> Listen 443 </IfModule>` in my ports.conf file so I assumed that would suffice.  The port is open on the firewall and has been for years.  That hasn't been touched.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Comment: Thanks @Iain.  When I do `ss -tnlp | grep :443` I get `LISTEN     0     128     :::443        :::*`  I guess this means that something is listening on port 443, right?  Can I assume that apache2 is listening on port 443 from this?